# Rails: verifying Paypal account and providing operations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, verification

My task is to transmit form to PayPal. I found this [link](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ACGetVerifiedStatusAPI), but I don't understand how to use it.

Also I need to provide constant connection PayPal acounts and my site for constant payments.

I should learn php to do this or what ?

CORRECTION

As I said first step is to verify PayPal account - transmit form from my site to PayPal.

My site will providind other sites with some javascript advertisements and I should provide payments for clicks.

Can you help me, when task is more specific now ?

Answer (score 0):

It is just a tip of the iceberg.

Yes, you need to learn server side programming in order to access PayPal API.

PayPal has multiple account type such as Website Payments Standards, Website Payments Pro, Payflow Gateway, PayPalExpress.

You need to make sure PayPal approve your merchant account before implementing it; they sometimes reject depending on your business.

If you post want you want to do, we can advice your better.

Good Luck!